# jQuery Mobile responsive thumbnail listview

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

i need help when constructing a responsive jQuery Mobile listview. I'm kind of stuck.

What i wanna have is a thumbnail listview with responsive (auto scaling) images, based upon the size of the viewport.

I'm stuck with the layout i'm trying to use `display: inline-table;`. Is there a way to accomplish or an alternative e.g. with media-queries?

I've made a jsfiddle in order to illustrate my concerns.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TorchMan/5fEmy/)

I would like to have the text vertically centered. 
The arrows should stay at their respective position even on resizing, but they're leaving their bounds, when the container shrinks.

There has once been a similar thread on github ([look here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1607)), where some guy posted a javascript-based solution, but i wonder if there is'nt a CSS3 solution.

Any help is appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**
This Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shreerang/K69pd/1/light/) is resizing the images, but not keeping the aspect ratio.

Comment: It is not clear exactly what result you want. What about your fiddle does not meet your needs?

Comment: I would like to have the text vertically centered, the arrows should stay at their respective position even on resizing, but they're leaving their bounds, when the container shrinks.

Comment: See this : 1) http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-grid/listview-grid.html Code: 2)http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-grid/

Comment: Thanks for the links, but actually i'm using jQM 1.3.2 and will upgrade later. But this is in some way a very cool solution. I love it. But for now i would like to have the images scale to the proportions of the viewport with having text and arrow-button inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have anything against html tables, this is pretty easy to do

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/84u74/1/)**

The table has separate cells for the image, text and thumbnail. Thumbnail td width is set to a specific pixel value so it never changes. The image td is set to 30% and the image sizes with viewport size. The text td takes up the rest of the space and vertically aligns to the middle. The rest is css styling to get the look you want:

```
<div class="div-list">    
<table class="listTable" >
    <tr>
        <td class="list-elem-thumb">  
            <img src="http://splusk.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/metro-2033-20091102111356147_640w1.jpg" />
        </td>
         <td class="list-elem-text">  
             asdasdasdasd
        </td>
         <td class="list-elem-ico">  
            <div class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

.div-list {
    border-radius: 0.6em;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 2px;
}
.listTable {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0.6em;
    border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;
}
.listTable tr:not(:first-child) > td {
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.listTable tr {
    background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #F1F1F1) repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    color: #222222;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
.listTable td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0;
}
.listTable .list-elem-thumb{
    width: 30%;
    padding: 2px;
}
.listTable .list-elem-thumb img {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    min-width: 125px;
}
.listTable .list-elem-text {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.listTable .list-elem-ico {
     width: 24px;
}
```

UPDATE: max-width does not work with FireFox, add width as well:

```
.listTable .list-elem-thumb img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    min-width: 125px;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/84u74/5/)**

Comment: Hi ezanker, thx for the efforts. But unfortunately the table is not scaling down the image when scaling the window down to a mobile viewport size. I've played with the percentage of img-width, but to no avail.

Comment: if you want the image to scale smaller, just change the min-height and min-width to smaller values, see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/84u74/3/

Comment: Aah, thx! Awesome! Somehow FireFox is not scaling the images on resizing the window, but Chrome is doing well. Seems as i've got to change my preferred browser now!

Comment: @TorchMan,  to make it work in FF and in Chrome, use width: 100% on the img, see my update to the answer...